# Badbox with Bibtex, how to fix it?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, line-breaking

**The problem:**

How to fix bad boxes done by bibtex? Latex copy and paste bibtex formatted entries to the text, but these entries exceed the correct space.

**Details:**
I using main.tex with this header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,oneside,openright]{book}
```

with this content at the end of it:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Referências Bibliográficas}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{12.Referencias_Bibliograficas}
```

I had too this bibtex entry:

```
@BOOK{chenpatton:99,
  AUTHOR =       "J. Chen and R. J. Patton",
  TITLE =        "Robust model-based fault diagnosis for dynamic systems",
  PUBLISHER =    "Dordrecht:   Kluwer Academic Publishers",
  YEAR =         "1999"
```

}

and finally this phrase:

```
A literatura apresenta muitas classes de estratégias para tratar o problema de FDI \cite{chenpatton:99}.
Estas estratégias podem ser, em geral, classificadas em abordagens baseadas em modelos quantitativos ~\cite{VR:03I} ~\cite{VR:03III} e em modelos qualitativos \cite{VR:03II} \cite{VR:03III}. Esta classificação é ilustrada na Figura~\ref{benchmark_1}.
```

My problem is, after the compilation I have this badbox

[image: Overfull]

and I don't know how to fix it.

See if I put a `~` before this `cite` looks like nothing happens and I have the same badbox. If I put a `\\` I lose the justified text

[image: Overfull2]

How can I solve this?

Comment: The information is insufficient; how do you load `natbib`?

Comment: Are you talking about the packages 

    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \usepackage{natbib}

?

If yes, they're disabled in my document, need them?

Comment: I had enable these packages but it takes the brackets `[]` and I need them.
My bibtex runs the following command:

>bibtex 12.Referencias_Bibliograficas.bib

Comment: I have some other problems like these in the document so I think it's better solve it instead just change the text.

Comment: If you say `\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}` and then use `\citep` instead of `\cite`, you get correct breaking.

Comment: Works fine^^ here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*We almost had a diplomatic crisis between Italy and Brazil, so per peer pressure, I'm writing down this answer. `:)`*

egreg and I came to the same solution, so here it is.

1. Use `\usepackage[square, authoryear]{natbib}` instead of `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`. The package options mean:

   - `square`: says that references are to be enclosed in square bracket rather than round parentheses.
   - `authoryear`: used for author–year citations.
2. Use `\citep` instead of `\cite`. Please note that `\citep` is a `natbib` exclusive command. It is used for parenthetical citations.

Hopefully we get rid of the bad blocks that way. `:)`

Comment: Crisis? Lol...for me it's all ok =)
You're welcome the see the World Cup here hehe

Answer (score 2):

Insert `\linebreak` where the line should end. Unlike `\\`, `\linebreak` will keep the line justified.